# Restore MYSQL Values after Column Variable Change

Tags: mysql, sql

Made a huge mistake and changed a column to BINARY(64) from varchar(30) and now my values look like:

`31393532353238380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Instead of the old:

`19525288`

Do I have any hope of restoring my original values (scared of what to do next, don't want to mess it up further).

Comment: Have you tried something like `ALTER TABLE <your table> CHANGE COLUMN <your column> <your column> VARCHAR(30);` ?

Comment: Yes, just tried that on a test table and it works.

Comment: Great! those kind of situations can be really scary...

Answer (score 2):

I copied the table real quick to preform some tests. Simply switching back the column to varchar(30) restored the previous values.

EDIT: In hindsight, I should have copied the table first thing and tested *changes* on the new table. This is much better than messing up the real table and testing *fixes* on the copied one.